# jQuery only works on second click on Ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm very new to Ajax and JQuery so please bear with me on this. I'm loading contents via Ajax on my page and the loaded content has a jQuery slideshow inside. When I click the link, everything runs ok, the content appears and all but the slideshow doesn't start at all. I need to click a second time on that link so the slideshow starts working.

This is my code so far:

```
var loadUrl = "map_fr.html";    
$("#loader").on('click',function(){
    $("#conteudo_projects").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });
```

Then I select a link with the id="loader" to load the content inside the #conteudo_projects DIV.

Can anyone help me? Why doesn't the slideshow start working on the first click? (If I test the slideshow directly on a page it works, so I know that there's no problem with that, it only happens when I load it via Ajax).

Thank You very much!

EDIT: I installed Firebug and although I still dont quite understand what's all that stuff that it displays, I noticed that under Net>JS, the first time I click the link I get the GET jQuery request (ajax.googleapis.com) greyed out. When I click again, the new request seems ok. Dont know if this helps, i'm trying everything to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: What is in `ajax_load`?  Also, if the problem is clicking on a link in the AJAX code, it would be more helpful to see that code.

Comment: @JeffB hi and thanks for your feedback. ajax_load is only refering to a "loading" image to give some feedback to the user while the content is loaded:  `var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='../assets/images/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";`. `The link I click to load the content is: <div id="mapping">
      <div id="marker_pt">
        <a id="loader"><img src="../assets/images/marker.png" class="marker_tool" title="France" /></a>
    </div>`

Comment: Just FYI - as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: What's the code that starts the slideshow?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the `on` api is incorrect.. Also have you made sure you are binding this event handler on `document.ready`.. Here is what the code should be:

Also your ajax load should probably be inside your event handler callback

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click',"#loader",function(){
      $.ajax(url:url,
             type:"POST",
             success:function(data){  
             $("#conteudo_projects").html(data); 
             });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery `load` to load content like this

This will show the ajax loading image which you stored in ajax_load variable and get content from yourUrl.Once it received the content from the ajax call it will replace the loading image mark up with the new content.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click',"#loader",function(){
     $("#conteudo_projects").html(ajax_load).fadeIn(300,function(){
        $(this).load(yourUrl);
     });
  });
});
```

jQuery `on` is available from 1.7+ onwards. If you are using a version before that, you may want to consider jQuery `live`.